# Google maps restrict map to one country only

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app I am using google maps for user to create locations on it. Right now users can create locations where ever they want but as I only provide the service in Norway I am looking to find a way to restrict the map view only to Norway.

Is there any option like this exists in gmaps? If not, what are the alternatives?